# How to change usb adapter properies by command ? Windows 7

Tags: windows, automation, tcl, driver

I want to change the "wireless Network Connection 2" 
"wireless mode" in device properties. How can it be done by command - to be automated (passable using tcl)? 
[image]

I also tried to change the registry key that follow the configuration but, comparing to older devices, it did nothing to the device! even after disable-enable or reboot the PC. TNX –

Comment: I'm not aware of GUI based approach with `Tcl`. But, if we can find a CLI based approach, then it can be done.

Comment: I don't mind CLI I can use it from TCL.
Do you know any ?